# LINQ: How can I centralize this condition .Where(job => !job.IsDeleted && !job.IsPrivate)

Tags: c#, linq

I often attach this condition to `_dbContext.Jobs`

Is there a way I can just do `_dbContext.Jobs.Public()` which is equivalent to

`_dbContext.Jobs.Where(job => !job.IsDeleted && !job.IsPrivate)`

then I can just add more filters to it like `_dbContext.Jobs.Public().Select(j => j.JobId)`

I tried

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static IEnumerable<Job> PublicJobs(IEnumerable<Job> jobs)
    {
        return jobs.Where(j => !j.IsDeleted && !j.IsPrivate);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work in this situation

```
from jl in _dbContext.JobLevels
from j in jl.Jobs.Where(job => !job.IsDeleted && !job.IsPrivate)
group jl by jl.JobLevelId into g
```

changing the second line to

```
from j in Helpers.PublicJobs(jl.Jobs)
```

somehow produces different result

Comment: Is jobs an `IQueryable` or just an `IEnumerable`? Perhaps am extension method on `IQueryable<Job>` is really what you need

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made two mistakes:

1. You are missing the `this` keyword in your method signature. The `this` keywords tells the compiler that this is an extension method.
2. You should use `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable` if you want the database to do the work

So the correct solution should be:

```
public static class Helpers
{
                                            // note the "this"
    public static IQueryable<Job> PublicJobs(this IQueryable<Job> jobs)
    {
        return jobs.Where(j => !j.IsDeleted && !j.IsPrivate);
    }
}
```

And make sure the `Helpers` class is in the same namespace or import the namespace with a `using` directive.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! :)